# Retrieve realm object equal to UUID

Tags: ios, swift, realm, swift4

Hopefully a quick one that I'm stuck on.

I'm passing a UUID String through a segue to the next VC.  This is definitely working because I am printing it on viewDidLoad.

What I want to do is retrieve the object with that UUID (workoutID).  I'm getting a crash of :

*"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid value', reason: 'Expected object of type string for property 'workoutID' on object of type 'WorkoutSessionObject', but received: 0'"*

When i try run the code below which I've adapted from other search related questions (I'm finding querying realm quite difficult to get my head round) :

```
class WorkoutSummaryController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    // Holder for my UUID passed via Segue which is working 
    var workoutID = UUID().uuidString

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        print(workoutID)

        // Set up the query to retrieve the object with the UUID that has been passed
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "workoutID = %A", workoutID)

        // Run the query and print the result which crashes
        let test = try! Realm().objects(WorkoutSessionObject.self).filter(predicate)
        print (test)
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `NSPredicate` format is flawed. You should be using `%@` for substituting variable's and `%K` for keypaths.

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "workoutID = %@", workoutID)
```

Comment: ah such a small change! You've saved me again David thank you!